# How can I add the current date without overwriting yesterday's date? Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, datetime

I'm using pandas to add a 'date' column to my dataframe that returns the value of the current day. I would like my code to record today's date and when my system is triggered again, record the date of the day it was executed WITHOUT OVERWRITING the other existing dates. My code looks like this:

```
atual_bixo = date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
extirpados.insert(loc = 10, column= 'Data', value= atual_bixo)
```

I also used a line of code in which:

```
read.csv had the parameter mode = 'a'
```

But this returned a duplicate of all my data that was already in the table

My read.csv looks like this:

```
base = pd.read_csv('cadastro_de_empregadores.csv', sep= ';', encoding="latin-1", skiprows= 5)
```

'skiprows' I use to indicate the beginning of the table, since this csv comes from another system with unnecessary lines for my analysis, which I cannot change the layout of the csv

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not very clear whether you want all these dates in just one column or make new rows every time a new date is added, I have outlined only the first way with a toy DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

# Create a DataFrame with Name and Age columns
data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Eve'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 28, 22]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Resulting DataFrame:

[image]

Consider adding a "date" column with empty lists. Thereafter you can fill this column each time your system is triggered. *Make sure to remove the if statement if it does not matter whether a date is already present in that column.* See below:

```
# Do this once 
df = df.assign(Dates=[[] for _ in range(len(df))])

# Each time the system is triggered
atual_bixo = date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x + [today_date] if atual_bixo not in x else x)
```

Resulting in (if we for example would trigger it for two consecutive days):

[image]

If this is not what you are searching for; make sure to provide more details about your DataFrame and the way you want to insert these dates.